# Installing PlatformIO for atom doesn't work

Tags: atom-editor, platformio

I had to reinstall atom and I am not able to install the PlatformIO IDE. I completely removed atom so everything should be back to default.

I reinstalled PlatformIO, by going to the install tab in the settings and installing it and restart atom after the download is done. But PIO isn't installed, if I click on any dropdowns that are from PIO, atom crashes. I have gotten this error message but I cant really make sense out of it:

[image]

There are no other windows open.

I am using MacOS 10.15.5